# Rails post external link on form and display it clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably simple but I can't figure out how to do it.

I simply want to be able to enter an external link in a form and then show it in the view. It should be clickable and open in a new tab.

I am using formtastic.

I tried:

form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @poll do |f| %>
<%= f.input :link %>

<% end %>
```

view:

```
<p><%= link_to @poll.link %></p>
```

I tried to enter https://www.google.com in the form.

Doing this it shows a clickable link https://www.google.com on view but when I click nothing happens.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need use `target: :_blank` with link as example: -

```
<li><%= link_to "My Link", @poll.link, target: :_blank %></li>
```

Comment: But the link is saved on polls table on link column. so what you posted as "My Link" is actually @poll.link. Which is what I tried already but does not work

Comment: I use the form to save url on link column on db. Problem is when I display it on view if I click it nothing happens

Comment: `<li><%= link_to "My Link", @poll.link, target: :_blank %></li>` try this

Comment: what does `@poll.link` return

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you :) @Catmal